# Need to Scroll horizantal table with fix headers

Tags: html, css, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I need to scroll a horizontal table with 2 fixed columns in the beginning. Here is a link to what I have so far, I know I am pretty close, I just can't get the wrapper to wrap the body of the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/ajamali/TBnqw/1147/

Any idea, what I am missing?